# Not able to open website using domain-name,published using DigitalOcean

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, django-1.11

I'm not able to view my website,created using Django 1.11.13,Python version 2.7.12;using it's domain name 'www.mysticprogrammer.net',which I bought in https://domains.google.I've used DigitalOcean,as platform for publishing.And,I've added the DigitalOcean DNS servers,viz.ns1,ns2 & ns3 as well.
The website opens fine,when I type IP address of the remote server in url.But when I type the domain name,viz.'www.mysticprogrammer.com' I get the error as follows :

```
  DisallowedHost at /
  Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.mysticprogrammer.net'. You may need to add 
  u'www.mysticprogrammer.net' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://www.mysticprogrammer.net/
  Django Version:   1.11.13
  Exception Type:   DisallowedHost
  Exception Value:  
  Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.mysticprogrammer.net'. You may need to add 
  u'www.mysticprogrammer.net' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
  Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
  packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 113
  Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
  Python Version:   2.7.12
  Python Path:  
  ['/home/django/django_project',
   '/home/django/django_project',
   '/usr/bin',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
   Server time: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 13:56:44 +0000
```

The error can be read by going to my domain name in url http://www.mysticprogrammer.net.
I've read all the former related questions,and added :

> "ALLOWED_HOSTS ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '159.65.158.7', 'fe80::74db:73ff:febe:b3da%eth0','www.mysticprogramer.net','mysticprogrammer.net'] "  in settings.py,and also in request.py,as mentioned in the error message.

But,nothing seems to be working.Please suggest the appropriate changes to be made.And how much time does it take for the changes made in the remote server, to reflect in the World Wide Web?!

Answer (score 0):

When going to `http://www.mysticprogrammer.net` the 500 error page clearly shows that `ALLOWED_HOSTS` only has `['127.0.0.1', '::1', '159.65.158.7', 'fe80::74db:73ff:febe:b3da%eth0']` but not the domain `mysticprogrammer.net` itself.

You shouldn't have to list the IPs (unless you really want to access the website by IP address) but you should restart whatever service you use to run your Django application (uwsgi? gunicorn?) so that your changes to `settings.py` get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is my 'settings.py' file.I did add 'www.mysticprogrammer.net' already.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdMx2.png)

[I've even added it in the 'allowed_hosts' of 'request.py' file,as mentioned in the exception location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlRCj.png)

I've also added 'service gunicorn restart',in my Putty CLI,after connecting to my droplet in DigitalOcean.

The link to the tutorial I followed,to reach till this point is this :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd

And,the particular video is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-CT_l1dnVU&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd&index=11